# Fetch Local Variables value in VBScript implented using clearscript

Tags: c#, debugging, vbscript, clearscript, iactivescript

I am implementing a debugger for Vbscript using Clearscript which is expected to display all the variables and their values upon hitting break point.

I am able to fetch all the variables using following code:

```
public static VBScriptEngine engine;
dynamic ome = engine.Evaluate("me"); 
foreach (var name in ome.GetDynamicMemberNames())
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", name, ome[name]);
```

The challenge here i am facing is that i am not able to fetch the context specific variables:
e.g.
A break point is set inside a function then upon hitting the break-point the variable list gets empty as per the above code.

Is there a way to fetch the context specific variables also(the variables inside the function)

Consider the following code:

```
abc = 123

def = 1432
Call hello()

Function hello()

 jas=123

 [breakpoint]

 ja = 14

End Function
```

Here on hitting the breakpoint it should display jas = 123

Please help!

You can see the reply from Clear script here:
https://clearscript.codeplex.com/discussions/640552#post1432299